# ducttape: sometimes skip task: branch on multiple variables

Tags: ducttape

Related to this question: [ducttape sometimes-skip task: cross-product error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23698707/ducttape-sometimes-skip-task-cross-product-error)

Say I have a plan like this:

```
task map_lexicon
    < in_lexicon=$pron_lex
    > out_lexicon=lex
    > out_w2p=lex.w2p
    > out_p2w=lex.p2w
{
    cp $in_lexicon $out_lexicon
    echo "" > $out_w2p
    echo "" > $out_p2w

}

task prune_lexicon
    # Prunes a lexicon
    < in_lexicon=$pron_lex
    > out_lex_pruned=lex.pruned
    > out_w2p_pruned=lex.w2p.pruned
    > out_p2w_pruned=lex.p2w.pruned
{
    cp $in_lexicon $out_lex_pruned
    echo "" > $out_w2p_pruned
    echo "" > $out_p2w_pruned
}

global {    
    lex1=/path/to/foo
    pron_lex=(PronLex: Lex1=$lex1)
}
```

Further down the pipeline, I want to create a branch that takes `map_lexicon` or `prune_lexicon` as a dependency. However, each task has 3 outputs that I need to use. Example:

```
global {
    lex_type=(LexType: raw=$out_lexicon@map_lexicon pruned=$out_lex_pruned@prune_lexicon)
}

task foo
    < in_lex=$in_lex@map_lexicon
    < in_w2p=$out_w2p@map_lexicon
    < in_p2w=$out_p2w@map_lexicon
    > bar
{
    echo $in_lex $in_w2p $in_p2w > bar
}
```

Is there a way to set up a sometimes-skip task to manage three variables within a single branch point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out all that's necessary is to define the additional variables with the same branch points.

```
global {
    lex=(LexType: raw=$out_lexicon@map_lexicon pruned=$out_lex_pruned@prune_lexicon)
    w2p=(LexType: raw=$out_w2p@map_lexicon pruned=$out_w2p_pruned@prune_lexicon)
    p2w=(LexType: raw=$out_p2w@map_lexicon pruned=$out_p2w_pruned@prune_lexicon)

}
```

Then define foo as:

```
task foo
    < in_lex=$lex
    < in_w2p=$w2p
    < in_p2w=$p2w
    > bar
{
    echo $in_lex $in_w2p $in_p2w > bar
}
```

Comment: Yep. You can also put those variables in the task declaration. Or in a global block. Whichever suits you.